# How can my sprite be responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I got a sprite picture which is a breadcrumbs menu. I want to change the y position of this sprite when the mouse is hover the menu's elements. 
There is no problem to do it with a fixed width website, but i can't resolve this with a responsive one...

Here is the live version : http://jsfiddle.net/RtqkD/
and my CSS  code :

```
   .services {
    height: 64px;
    width: auto;
    background: transparent url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3894287/sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.services #Et1 {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
.services #Et1, .services #Et2, .services #Et3, .services #Et4 {
    height: 65px;
}
.services li {
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
}
.services li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.services li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Any tips ?

**EDIT**
After the @Sven comment i made a more complete live version of my issue here with CSS, HTMLand Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/RtqkD/2/

Comment: Sorry but that peace of code shows nothing. You must show us what works for you and how you want it and then what works not for you and where your problems are.

Comment: May be this will give you some direction: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Comment: Can you describe what part of the sprite you want to use at different resolutions?

Comment: @mitch This background image needs to be responsive.

Comment: @SvenBieder I know this little piece of code means barely nothing, but my question is really, how can this small piece of code be responsive, how can this sprite be 100% width whatever the website width will be

Comment: When you have it as a background-image than you have 2 possibilities. You can make a repeat-x (given that the sprite is seamlessly repeatable) or make the image so big that it fills every screen resolution.

Comment: @SvenBieder I changed the jsfiddle with mor details of what i need :)

Comment: @x_vi_r at first get rid of the `backgound-size`, next cut the image at the right position that it is repeatable and finally set `background-repeat` to repeat-x. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, lets start with the fact that the way you're spriting that is totally unnecessary. I see why, but with some careful coding it can be gotten around.

Using the `:before` pseudo element, I created the triangles after each item. Now each item reacts to the hover on the anchor using CSS rather than jQuery (much neater). Browser support won't go down to IE7, but neither do most things.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robsterlini/RtqkD/5/ (**EDIT** sorted the padding issues http://jsfiddle.net/robsterlini/RtqkD/6/)

And here are the elements used: [arrow sprite](http://i43.tinypic.com/2rfsdxl.jpg), [background sprite](http://i39.tinypic.com/ir50zr.jpg) (and if you wanted to be really tight with the sprites, you could even sprite them together, just be careful with how you do it.

Took me a little while to figure it out, so if you need any explaining then give me a shout :) Hope that helps!

Comment: Woo nice, it really works great. I'm going to try this in my project :)

Comment: No probs mate. If it solves the issue you could mark this as the answer. ;)